# Point wise convergence does not imply convergence in $L^p$ -example-

Tags: solution-verification, lp-spaces, pointwise-convergence

A very quick and simple question (i ve nobody else to ask it).

To prove that pointwise convergence does not imply convergence in $L^p$ we just simply have to take for example a sequence of functions that point wise converge to a function that is not in $L^p$ / that is unbounded in $L^p$

For example on $\omega \in (0;1)$:
$X_n(\omega ) = \frac{1}{\omega +n^{-1}}\overset{a.s.}{\rightarrow}\frac{1}{\omega }=X(\omega )$
But obviously $X_n(\omega )$ can't converge to $X(\omega )$ in $L^1(0;1)$ as $X(\omega ) = 1/\omega$ isn't even in $L^1(0;1)$

Comment: what is the question ?

Comment: Yes, that's an example of a sequence of $L^1$ functions whose pointwise limit is not in $L^1$. Arguably this is not an example to show "in $L^p$, pointwise convergence does not imply convergence in norm" - there are stronger examples of sequences of $L^p$ functions with pointwise limit in $L^p$ but they don't converge in norm (and it's good manners I think to give examples for *all* $p$).

Comment: Also, I assume you mean $X_n(\omega) = 1/(\omega + n^{-1})$...

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen thk i ve edited my message